# How to launch an Azure Functions local instance from a C# exe?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Functions project which I would like to host locally. The project builds fine, but it does not produce any executables, only DLLs (I used the default setup proposed by VS).

How do I write an executable that would launch the service as a child process or within itself?

Answer (score 0):

First the Azure Functions Project is to be in running state and then the Console application needs to be executed to run the Function API.

**Result**:

**Console App which hits the Function API (Http Trigger) specified**:
[image]

**Function App Output which is in running State**:

[image]

**Function App Code**:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace KrishNet6FunApp
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string responseMessage = "Hello Krishna, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
            log.LogInformation($"{responseMessage}");
            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

**Console App Code which calls the Function App API**:

Note: Http Client Code taken from the C# Corner [Article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-web-api-using-httpclient/).

```
CallWebAPIAsync().Wait();
 static async Task CallWebAPIAsync()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:7206/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Function1/");
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);

    }
}
```